# Delete "Paragon" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The game Paragon was shut down by EPIC Games. Should we delete the "Paragon" tag due to this inconvenience? I can not delete it as I do not know how to do so.

Comment: *shrug* I don't see a compelling reason to. We kept all the questions for the game Glitch when it closed, etc.

Comment: And for City of Heroes.  There's no reason to delete it.

Answer (score 12):

Just because a game gets shut down, it doesn't mean we need to delete all existence of it from the site. It could still be helpful to someone watching a video of the game or something. It doesn't hurt anything to leave it, so why put in the effort to remove something that could have some positive impact and has little to no negative impact? If anything needs to be done with the tag, just put a note in the tag wiki stating when the game was shut down.